# Is this a trick question in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Calculate the probability of $P(A|B')$ given that $A$ and $B$ are independent and $P(A)=\frac{1}{3}$

My intuition tells me since $P(A)= \frac{1}{3}$ and $A$ does not depend on $B$ the answer should just be $\frac{1}{3}$ and even more since I looked at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956384/probability-venn-diagrams-independent).

Is this really just a trick question or is there more to it?

Comment: That’s it! $\space$

Comment: Is $B'$ a typo or does it mean something? Possibly the non-occurence of $B$? In that case you answer is still right of course.

Comment: @kmm $B', B^c, \neg B$ and others are common ways to write the complementary event to $B$, i.e. $\Omega \setminus B$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space.

Comment: No need to tell me. Curious, I've seen $B^c$, $\lnot B$, $\overline{B}$ but never before $B'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Bayes theorem for these kind of exercises :

$$\begin{align}P(A \mid B) &= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \\&= P(A)& \text{since A et B are independent}\end{align}$$

And you are right here intuition is quite clear, yet be carefull with intuition when working with conditional porbabilities since some situations can be somehow tricky.
But yes that's it.

Comment: I was trying to use total probability $P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B')P(B')$ but I couldn't figure out how to solve for P(B) which would give me the answer. I quickly realized however, that this was likely a trick.